# Syntax of catch condition in php

Tags: php, class, syntax

In the catch statement of the below example from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

```
<?php
//create function with an exception
function checkNum($number) {
   if($number>1) {
       throw new Exception("Value must be 1 or below");
   }
return true;
}

//trigger exception in a "try" block
try {
    checkNum(2);
    //If the exception is thrown, this text will not be shown
    echo 'If you see this, the number is 1 or below';
}

//catch exception
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The catch  braces have Exception $e where Exception is the class and $e is an object of that class but objects are declared as follow in php right ?

```
object_name = new class_name
```

so is $e something different? If not why we write className before the object. Please explain the syntax.

I tried to look some different syntax to declare class in php but I was  not able to find anything like this.

Comment: `$e` is an object of class `Exception`.

Comment: so can objects also be declared like that

Comment: It is __not__ declaring of an object.

Comment: When you throwing Exception you are creating an object, and that object get passed to catch block `catch(Exception $e)`

Comment: we write className before the object becuase we want to accept in $e only an instanceOf Exception class this is a type hinting you can learn more about it [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: Thanks @AmitBisht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already an instance of exception that is being passed into the catch block. If you were declaring your own exception it would looks as follows:

```
class TestException extends Exception
{

    public function __construct($msg, $code = 0, Exception $previousException = null) {
        parent::__construct($msg, $code, $previousException);
    }

    //How will it print if you just echo the class
    public function __toString() {
        return 'A test string';
    }

}


//create function with an exception
function checkNum($number) {
   if($number>1) {
       throw new TestException("Value must be 1 or below");
   }
return true;
}

try {
    checkNum(2);
    //If the exception is thrown, this text will not be shown
    echo 'If you see this, the number is 1 or below';
}

//catch exception
catch(TestException $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```